# Has anyone run mono for .NET on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: .net, mono, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

EB is based on Apache Tomcat 6/7. I'm a .NET guy so not very familiar with Apache servers. I guess there are two questions. First can you run the mod_mono server on Tomcat 6/7? Secondly, if so can you run it on Amazon EB?

We have an enterprise app largely written in Java but we have one core module written in .NET and I'm looking for a way to run the whole thing in a PaaS environment. I think this means I can either a) run all my Java stuff on Microsoft Azure (the .NET program will of course work here) or b) run my one .NET program and all my Java code on Amazon EB.

Thanks!

Comment: This probably belongs on serverfault

Comment: Apache Tomcat cannot use modules for Apache HTTPD.  Tomcat is written in Java so mod_mono won't work with it.  You would need an Apache HTTPD server in front of Tomcat with mod_mono running.

Answer (score 0):

If you could tweak the bootstrapping for mono using .ebextensions, perhaps you might find this approach useful:

http://docs.ingenieux.com.br/project/beanstalker/using-arbitrary-platforms.html

Basically, you're submitting a node.js app to exec your mono app :)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the details provided, you will be able to host the solution on an IaaS platform. You can do that better using Azure VM role. Currently Amazon EB supports .Net based applications as well. Hence you may consider using a combination of Apache tomcat (6 & 7 support out of the box) and .Net application on windows instance (IIS 7.5 & 8 are supported) using a separate .Net Amazon EB application. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can very easily run Java applications on Azure PaaS, you just need a simple .NET wrapper to start up your application and deploy the Java runtime in your package too